# Two decimal points not working

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me figure out why my two decimal points are not working for .toFixed(2).  I am new to jquery and any help would be much appreciated. When I multiply .0625, I get more than two decimal places now

```
$('.grandtotal').text(parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));
```

Working

```
$('.tax_total').text(.0625 * parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));
```

Not Working

Comment: the bottom one only rounds to 2 the result of `parseFloat(...)` but then it gets multiplied by `.0625` (which is more then 2 decimals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.tax_total').text(parseFloat(grandTotal * .0625).toFixed(2));
```

You're trying to add `.0625` after make `grandTotal` to two decimal and that makes it more that Two decimal again.

Answer (score 0):

The member access operator (`.`) has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the multiplication operator (`*`), so the `toFixed` gets applied before the multiplication.

Add parentheses to do it in the right order:

```
$('.tax_total').text((.0625 * parseFloat(grandTotal)).toFixed(2));
```